# Clear Zend Page cache programmatically

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, zend-cache

I am using Zend's full page caching for certain URL's. Is there a way to clear the page cache for a certain URL programmatically....(when the content of the URL is modified)

Comment: This helps: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.theory.html ?

Answer (score 0):

On the method that does the update of the data shown at a certain URL, you have to call a cleanup method.
For example, if you have in cache the URL "/dog", saved with that id ("/log"), when the data of this page change you have to execute:

```
$cache->remove('/dog');
```

And I loved this: http://devzone.zend.com/article/4457

Comment: Found this link: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend_page_cache_-_php_api.htm .........this is specific to zend servers full page caching....and not data caching